# Angular: directive on custom formControl results in error

Tags: angular, typescript

When I add my custom **idNumber** directive on to the child HTML element, all works fine. I would like to use it in the parent class. That however doesn't work.

```
// custom directive ////////
@Directive({
selector: "[idNumber]"
})
export class IcoDirective implements OnInit {
formControl: FormControl;
constructor(private control: NgControl) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.formControl = <FormControl>this.control.control;
    this.addValidators(this.formControl);
}

addValidators(formControl: FormControl) {
    formControl.setValidators(Validators.compose(
            [... some validators...]
        ));
    }


// child HTML ////////
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput idNumber // if I put the directive here, all works fine.
    [formControl]="idNumberFormControl"
</mat-form-field>

// child TS ////////
ngOnInit() {
    this.idFormControl = new FormControl();
    this.idFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.manageUserInput(this.idFormControl );
    });
}

insertIntoForm(parentFormGroup: FormGroup): void {
    parentFormGroup.addControl(this.name, this.idFormControl );
}


// parent HTML ////////
<custom-input-string
    idNumber // if I put the directive here (not in child), I get an error.
    [name]="'idNumber'">
</custom-input-string>

// parent TS ////////
@ViewChild(CustomInputStringComponent) child: CustomInputStringComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.child.insertIntoForm(this.signupForm);
    }, 0);
}
```

**The error I get:**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)
> [MatInput -> NgControl]:  
>  
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatInput -> NgControl]:  
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl! 
> Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatInput -> NgControl]:  
>  
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatInput -> NgControl]:  
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!

I know it has something to do with the dependency injection, and I tried to look for a solution all over the internet. Unsuccessfully so far.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not on the input anymore.

You have to use `ContentChild` to get the component you want, then use the control of the said component.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttt2df-trgv5d?file=app/id-number.directive.ts) (based on your previous question)

```
@ContentChild(CustomComponentComponent) component: CustomComponentComponent;

constructor(
) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.component && this.component.control.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Could you please modify your answer to fit my code? Thank you. And also - what does the 'this.component && ...' do in your ngAfterViewInit method?

Comment: That's a shorthand for a `if` : if the left of the `&&` is falsy, the right of the `&&` won't be ran (I'm a lazy JS coder). The answer I gave you is basically the same as your code, I just named my component `CustomComponentComponent` instead of `CustomInputStringComponent`. The important part is, don't use `ViewChild`, use `ContentChild`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the 'this.component && ...' stuff. I forgot how weird Javascript actually is. I'm *thiiis* close to accepting your answer, because I figured it out thanks to you and it works. However, I would like you to update your answer here and on StackBlitz (as you did in your comment), so other people with the same problem will have easier time comprehending it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ran into the same error..... i tried to apply a directive using `NgControl` on a component (e.g. mat-button) and got the same error, while on an HTML component it worked fine. Error message did not exactly point me in the right direction. Have not tried (yet) to build a directive that works on both (custom) components (nested HTML elements) AND regular elements.